# Redimencionamento com JQuery

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu, redimensionamento

Estou tentando colocar um menu responsivo no meu site, preciso que quando a tela for redimensionada para determinado tamanho ele se torne responsivo e quando aumentar novamente ele volte para a div "normal"

```
$(function () {
var detectViewPort = function(){
        var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();
        if (viewPortWidth <= 740) {
            $('nav#menu-mobile').mmenu();
        }
        else {
         //... como desabilitar???
        }
    };

    $(function(){
        detectViewPort();
    });

    $(window).resize(function () {
        detectViewPort();
    });
```

Eu consigo fazer ele ficar como quero quando redimensiono o navegador para um tamanho igual ou menor a 740, mas depois quando aumento novamente eu não consigo "desfazer" o processo, alguém saberia como me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

Veja se esse plugin the atende: http://responsivemobilemenu.com/en/

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://responsivemobilemenu.com/demo/rmm-css/responsivemobilemenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://responsivemobilemenu.com/demo/rmm-js/responsivemobilemenu.js"></script>

<body>


<br>
<br>
<br>



<!-- DEFAULT (GRAPHITE) STYLE -->

<div class="rmm graphite" style="max-width: 638.4px;"><div class="rmm-toggled rmm-closed" style=""><div class="rmm-toggled-controls"><div class="rmm-toggled-title">Menu</div><div class="rmm-button"><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></div></div><ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-me">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#links">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sitemap">Sitemap</a></li> 
       </ul></div>
        <ul class="rmm-main-list" style="">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-me">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#links">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sitemap">Sitemap</a></li> 
       </ul>
</div>



<br>
<br>
<br>



<!-- SAPPHIRE STYLE -->

<div class="rmm sapphire" data-menu-style="sapphire" style="max-width: 638.4px;"><div class="rmm-toggled rmm-closed" style=""><div class="rmm-toggled-controls"><div class="rmm-toggled-title">Menu</div><div class="rmm-button"><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></div></div><ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-me">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#links">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sitemap">Sitemap</a></li> 
       </ul></div>
        <ul class="rmm-main-list" style="">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-me">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#links">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sitemap">Sitemap</a></li> 
       </ul>
</div>


<br>
<br>
<br>


<!-- MINIMAL STYLE -->
<div class="rmm minimal" data-menu-style="minimal" style="max-width: 632.1px;"><div class="rmm-toggled rmm-closed" style=""><div class="rmm-toggled-controls"><div class="rmm-toggled-title">Menu</div><div class="rmm-button"><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span></div></div><ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-me">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#links">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sitemap">Sitemap</a></li> 
       </ul></div>
        <ul class="rmm-main-list" style="">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-me">About me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#links">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sitemap">Sitemap</a></li> 
       </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2**

Tente o seguinte:

```
$(function () {
    var detectViewPort = function(event){
        var viewPortWidth = $(window).width();
        if (viewPortWidth <= 740) {
            $('nav#menu-mobile').mmenu();
        }
        else {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    };

    $(function(){
        detectViewPort();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(event) {
        detectViewPort(event);
    });
});
```

Comment: Olá amigo, obrigado pela resposta, mas eu já tenho um plugin que funciona, e eu poderia por exemplo criar 2 menus de definir qual vai aparecer via css. Mas nesse caso o que eu quero é saber como eu "desabilito" via jquery o menu responsivo. Aqui está o problema: 

if (viewPortWidth <= 740) {
            $('nav#menu-mobile').mmenu();
        }
        else {
         //... como desabilitar???
//esse é o problema
        }

Comment: Qual é o plugin?

Comment: o plugin é o mmenu

Comment: Veja o EDIT 2..

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/on-and-off-canvas.html

Comment: chegou a tentar o EDIT 2?